# Polymer app-toolbar with drop down menus

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

In Polymer 2 I would like to create an app-toolbar with menu buttons that on-click show a dropdown menu, similar to a classical desktop application. The app-toolbox seems to be a great start for a responsive solution and there are examples for creating toolbars with simple navigation buttons/links.

What I don't find are examples on creating dropdown menus in the toolbar.

My questions:

Which component should I use to show a dropdown menu in the app-toolbar? Maybe iron-dropdown? Is there any example?

What would happen to the dropdown menu when on narrow screens the app-toolbar collapses to the single menu button? Would the drawer that is shown by the menu button allow me to show the dropdown menus?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [paper-dropdown-menu](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu), or [iron-dropdown](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-dropdown) or some similar.
But you should pay attention for the `iron-overlay-behavior` dropdown content max-height.